# Randomize letters in string in C

Tags: c, random, permutation

I have for example "asd" and I want it to be randomized to DAS, DSA, SAD, you know. How can I code this? Tried a few solutions but It didnt really work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    printf("type in the word\n");
    char haslo[128];
    scanf("%s", haslo);
    char set[128];
    char hasloa[128];
    strcpy(set, haslo);
    unsigned int Ind = 0;
    srand(time(NULL) + rand());
    int len = strlen(set);
    while(Ind < len)
    {
        hasloa[Ind++] = set[rand()%62];
    }
    hasloa[len] = '\0';
    printf("%s", hasloa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And those solutions were?

Comment: Show us "what didn't really work"

Comment: These are called [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). What have You tried so far?

Comment: What makes you think that your solution could possibly work ?

Comment: Use `set[rand()%len]` to randomize.  More work needed for random permutation.

Answer (score -1):

Change 62 inside the while loop to "len"